# Cannot publish new table from database project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am using vs 2015. I just added a new sql table creation script into a database project. I also added some scripts for foreign keys and related items. None of these changes get deployed when I publish the project.

The publish completes without errors, but I don't see the new table. When I open the generated publish script I find no reference to the new table, which of course is why it is not getting deployed.

When I look at the Advanced Publish Settings within the publish screen I can see many possible settings to change, but I'm not sure which one I should modify. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your information it's hard to say, if my answer was not the root cause let me know to delete my answer:

Right click on your table script, and change `Build Action` to `Build`

Comment: Yep that was it. Can you tell me why that works though?

Comment: @DavidChoi, glad it works, Database project will make script based on files that are included for build, the other files can be used for pre or post deployment( it means for pre and post the build action must be None)